# Does Linux have some tools like mtree in *BSD?

Tags: linux, command-line-interface, filesystems

I want to check all system files change every week. So I want to get a tool like mtree in BSD.

Answer (score 4):

Consider using [Tripwire](http://tripwire.org/). Tripwire will allow you to monitor files for changes by recording their checksums and then encrypting them. It's not integrated in with the system as well as mtree is on BSD, so it requires more configuration and upkeep but it will get the job done.

Answer (score 3):

RedHat/CentOS has **aide** for file integrity checking.  See:

http://people.redhat.com/sgrubb/files/hardening-rhel5.pdf

Answer (score 1):

The mtree from FreeBSD ships as /usr/bin/fmtree with the freebsd-buildutils* package in Ubuntu 14.04.

- http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/freebsd-buildutils

Answer (score 0):

And there is [samhain](http://www.la-samhna.de/samhain/). Another HIDS (host based intrusion detection system).

Answer (score 0):

Consider implementing OpenVAS, which will thoroughly scan your hosts.  Various host integrity checkers can be integrated.
http://openvas.org/
[irc://irc.oftc.net/openvas](http://irc://irc.oftc.net/openvas)